# Python, numerical triangle with a few prints, and mostly loops and ifs

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I haven't come even close, this is the way it should be displayed:

```
100
200   202
300   304   308
400   406   412   418
 …
 …
 …


900   916   932      …              1028
```

This is what I have been trying so far:

```
for i in range(100,1000,100):
  
  for j in range(100,1000,100):
    

  
    print(i,"  ",end="")
  
  
  print("")
  







  

x=0
for i in range(1,10,1):
  x+=2
  for j in range(1,10,1):
    x+=2
    

    print(x,"  ",end="")
  x=0  
  
  
  print("")
  






for i in range (10):

  for j in range(10):


      x=(j*2+(i*2*j))
    
      print(x,"  ",end="")

 
      
  print("")  











  for i in range(100,1000,100):
  
    for j in range(100,1000,100):
    

  
      print(i,"  ",end="")
  
  
  print("")
```

Comment: With the user name "Python lover", your code really suggests otherwise. Show Python (and programmers in general) some love by removing the insane amount amount of vertical whitespace in this program so that it's at least readable.

Comment: It is sad to read this demeaning comment, I need those extra lines to understand what's going on, I suffer from dyslexia and am not a super master programmer. I think you are so fortunate to be able to understand so quickly and be so great in programming. I am not. But then I think that if you are so intolerant, that means something other than an insignificant question from a stranger most be hurting you. I mean, why even bother with me? Anyway. I hope whatever put you in this bad mood gets solved.

Comment: You are reading way more into that than was intended. It was a tongue-in-cheek observation intended to highlight an area for improvement. Layout is just as important as the code itself. This is especially true in Python. Perhaps there are other ways you can assist readability for yourself without all that spacing. The usual way is to group small blocks of code together and have a one- or two-line comment above that explains in human terms what the code does. I've never encountered anybody who finds inconsistent and excessive spacing more readable than consistent spacing with logical grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for index, i in enumerate(range(100, 1000, 100)):
    num = i
    for j in range(index + 1):
        print(num, end=" ")
        num += index * 2
    print()
```

OUTPUT:

```
100 
200 202 
300 304 308 
400 406 412 418 
500 508 516 524 532 
600 610 620 630 640 650 
700 712 724 736 748 760 772 
800 814 828 842 856 870 884 898 
900 916 932 948 964 980 996 1012 1028
``
```

Comment: How did you do that? What principle? What logic? The best I could do is a primitive program which I am attaching it as an answer , my program does solve it but it looks very very primitive, how could you do it so fast? I was looking to find two for loops to solve it but I had to use  9,

Comment: Structurally the main points are as follows.
1. the first element of each row is incremented by 100 row by row starting from 100
2. the numbers in each row are an equal series and the incremental values between the elements are also increasing row by row (from 0 in the first row, to 2 in the second, to 4 in the third ... (combined with the index of the list, which is still n*2, where n starts at 0)

Comment: In terms of code.
The first for loop means that there are 9 rows, the first element of each row is incremented by 100, starting from 100
The second for loop is responsible for printing all the numbers in each line, using the above rule: next number = previous number + index*2

Answer (score 0):

```
      for i in range(100,100+1,1):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      print("")
      
      for i in range(200,202+1,2):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      print("")
      
      for i in range(300,308+1,4):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      print("")
      
      for i in range(400,418+1,6):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      print("")
        
      
      for i in range(500,532+1,8):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      print("")
      
      
      for i in range(600,650+1,10):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      
      
      print("")
      
      
      
      for i in range(700,772+1,12):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      
      
      print("")
      
      
      
      
      for i in range(800,898+1,14):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      
      
      print("")
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      for i in range(900,1028+1,16):
        print(i,"  ",end="")
      
      print("")
```

Comment: My solution is very primitive I knwo, but I wanted to post it regardless, I Wonder how maya was able to soleve it do fast? what principles did he use?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).